# Average of calculated quantity of discrete data

Tags: electric-current, voltage, power, discrete, data-analysis

Let's say I have two discrete series of a physical quantity, current *I* and voltage *V* taken at the same time interval in a DC circuit. Now, I want to estimate the average power *P* over *N* measurements, what is the difference between calculating the average of individual instantaneous power vs the power of the average of each series, eg :
$$ P = \frac{ \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} V_iI_i }{N}$$
vs
$$ P =  \frac{ \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} V_i }{N}\frac{ \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} I_i }{N}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the two formulae given, the second formula is almost certainly wrong, as the average of the product of two variables is *not generally equal* to the product of the averages of the two variables. The difference between these two is called the [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance),
$$\langle xy\rangle-\langle x\rangle\langle y\rangle\triangleq\operatorname{cov}(x,y)$$
where $\langle\cdot\rangle$ indicates the average. So unless the covariance is zero (i.e., the two samples are *uncorrelated*), then using the second formula would be wrong.

However, the first equation is also not really right. For power, it is generally more proper to consider the average as the product of the [*root mean squares*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square#Average_electrical_power) of the voltage and current,
$$P_\text{avg}=V_\text{RMS}\times I_\text{RMS}\equiv\left(\frac{1}{t_2-t_1}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}V(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t\right)^{1/2}\times\left(\frac{1}{t_2-t_1}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}I(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t\right)^{1/2}.$$
The discrete form would then be,
$$P_\text{avg}=V_\text{RMS}\times I_\text{RMS}\equiv\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_iV_i^2}\times\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_iI_i^2}.$$